# setting database value to a property value of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, properties

I'm trying to create a new object in the database which will take a value of a database entry based on the choice of a DropDownList.

In the following example I want a new "Domena" object to hold the value of property "Cena" which belongs to Class TLD, the property "Cena" has been created and it's in the database as decimal value. It should take the value of a "Cena" from TLD Class when given TLD has been selected from the DropDownList.

Here's the Domena Class model :

```
public class Domena
{
public int DomenaID { get; set; }
public int TLDID { get; set; } // foreign id
public int KlientID { get; set; }
// irrelevant code omitted
public decimal Cena { get; set; } // value which should be copied from "Cena" from TLD CLASS
public virtual TLD TLD { get; set; }
public virtual Klient Klient { get; set; }
```

}

Here's the TLD class :

```
public class TLD
{
public int TLDID { get; set; }
public string Typ { get; set; }
public decimal Cena { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Domena> Domeny { get; set; }
}
```

I've been looking at :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/30/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-5-working-with-property-values.aspx
but I couldn't find a solution for my self. What ive tried already is this code in my HTTP GET Create action:

```
    public ActionResult Create(TLD cena)
    {
        ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
        ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "Firma");
           var model = new Domena
            {
                Cena = cena.Cena
            };
        return View();
    }
```

But the Value is still 0.00. I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Any help would be very welcomed.

---

Edit after bcr answer :

I'm sorry I haven't put all the data needed. I have actually modified the httpget and httpPost methods since ive added another dropdownmenu to it. Here they are :

HTTPGET :

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
        ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "Firma");
        ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(db.StatusDomeny, "StatusID", "Status");

        return View();
    }
```

HTTPPOST :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Domena domena)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Domeny.Add(domena);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.TLDID = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ", domena.TLDID);
        ViewBag.KlientID = new SelectList(db.Klienci, "KlientID", "Firma", domena.KlientID);
        ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(db.StatusDomeny, "StatusID", "Status", domena.StatusID);
        return View(domena);
    }
```

My View looks like this :

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TLDID, "TLD")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("TLDID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TLDID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KlientID, "Klient")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("KlientID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KlientID)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusID, "Status")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("StatusID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusID)
    </div>
```

As of now, as you can see I've deleted anything related to "Cena" as I couldn't get it to work.

As I understand in the httpGet method the line :

```
model.TldDropDown = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
```

should be

```
model.TldList = new SelectList(db.TLDs, "TLDID", "Typ");
```

based on what you've put in the CreateViewModel :

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TldList {get; set;}
```

Am I right ?

However, when I try this, im getting an error msg saying :

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' to IEnumearble. An explicit conversion exist. Are you missing a cast?

Maybe more explanation of what I'm trying to achive :

I have a Create page for Domena objects. There is a DropDownList for list of TLDs from db.TLDs listed by TLD.Typ. I want my httpGet / httpPost methods to know that if let's say TLDID = 1 (it's displayed TLD.Typ value from the DropDownList) was chosen then it should assign the value of "Cena" which belongs to TLDID = 1 to Domena.Cena property.

Hope that explains it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification, it helps quite a bit. So is your view bound to the `Domena` entity as its model? That's not in your view sample, but I'm going to assume so.

Basically, once you get the TLD ID that the user selected, you'll need to get the TLD entity from the context, and that TLD entity holds the Cena value with which you want to populate the new Domena object's property. I'm not sure whether/where you'd want to put the Cena value on the screen, but you could have that as a property of the `DomenaViewModel` and set it in the POST action, after you've saved the new `Domena` to the DB.

Assuming the `Domena` classs is an entity, it's not really great to use an entity as a view model, as has been discussed many times here. The general approach seems to be to have something like a `DomenaViewModel` class or a `DomenaDto` class to use as a view model. You then map the appropriate fields to and from the view model and entity as needed. `AutoMapper` is a popular option to help automate and organize this process; I use `ValueInjecter.` In this particular example, doing it manually should be simple enough to illustrate the point.

Another thing is that the `ViewBag` is used for the `SelectLists` but the `ViewBag` is never referenced in the `View`. I'd do away with using the `ViewBag` altogether here and stick with the `ViewModel` approach. I'll keep it simple, focusing on the TLD and Domena classes, and just what is needed for the Create actions. A similar approach would be used for the other drop-downs and entities.

Note that you'd want to take care that you're not adding another `Domena` to the DB that is exactly like one that already exists (has all the same foreign keys and values), unless that's what you specifically want to do. Basing this drop-down approach on Scott Allen's [article](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

```
public class DomenaViewModel
{
    public List<TLD> Tlds {get; set;} 
    public int SelectedTldId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TldItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(Tlds, "TLDID", "Typ"); }
    }

    // irrelevant code omitted
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new DomenaViewModel
      {
          Tlds = db.TLDs.ToList();
      };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(DomenaViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var tld = db.TLDs.Find(model.SelectedTldId); // assuming you're using DbContext
        if (tld != null)
        {
            // the mapping is best served in a different method, but we'll do it here for now
            var newDomena = new Domena
              {
                  TLD = tld,
                  Cena = tld.Cena
              }
            db.Domeny.Add(newDomena);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    viewModel.Tlds = db.TLDs.ToList();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The relevant part of the view:

```
@model DomenaViewModel

<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTldId, Model.TldItems)
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @bcr. Thanks for your help. I've edited my post with more explanation and data. Hope you can take a quick look!

Comment: Hi @bcr. Thanks for that. It took me a while to get it working with 3 different dropdownlist and another 15 different properties, but this actually worked, everything is being correctly saved in my database. The only thing I had to change was public List<TLD> to public IQueryable<TLD> because there was a conversion error coming up while building. I would like to ask you about your opinion on "Note that you'd want to take care that you're not adding another Domena to the DB that is exactly like one that already exists". Could you please shed some light on how to best achive that ?

Comment: Hi @Abbys, glad I was able to help. I edited my answer to call `ToList()` when retrieving the `TLDs`. I'd suggest doing that, and putting back the `List<TLD>` type on the property in the view model. This way the query is executed right away and it returns the list of `TLDs` from the DB, rather than essentially lazy loading them via the `IQueryable` that would be returned if we didn't use `ToList()`.

As far as taking care regarding what to add to the DB, I'm just pointing out that one needs to be aware of the relationships between entities when adding/removing them.

Comment: ive tried leaving it as LIST but the code will just not compile. It kept throwing an error like this for each * = db.TLDs in the controller : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<DATname.Models.TLD>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DATname.Models.TLD>' - for some reason it could only accept IQueryable as apparently DbSet cant convert the data to a List

Comment: @Abbys did you add the `ToList()` to the calls to the two or so `db.TLDs` calls as well? They need to be like `db.TLDs.ToList()` which I've updated in my answer above.